# Preg_replace only when it's the only word

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

How would I preg_replace a string, when it only exists out of that one word?

Example:
Coming in are:

1. G-star Raw
2. G-STAR
3. G-star

I would like to change them all to G-STAR RAW:

```
$x = preg_replace('/(G-star)\b/', 'G-STAR RAW', $x);`
```

But I am getting also:

```
G-STAR RAW RAW
```

It's also replacing the G-Star in example nr 1. How would I do a replace saying it can only work when it's exactly that string, not when more words are in that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an optional match that looks for the existing `raw` within the text:

```
(G-star(?: raw)?)\b
```

In the `preg_replace()`, it would look like:

```
$x = preg_replace('/\b(G-star(?: raw)?)\b/i', 'G-STAR RAW', $x);
```

Also note the added `i` option in the regex to ignore case sensitivity.

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/Fsx5kIgi) Output:

```
1  G-star Raw = G-STAR RAW
2  G-STAR = G-STAR RAW
3  G-star = G-STAR RAW
```

**UPDATE** Added a leading `\b` to prevent "g-star" from appearing in other words like 'big-star'.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Good catch; I've updated my answer (and codepad sample) to have the leading `\b`. Thanks =]

Comment: I am trying it now (need to do a big feed import for it. Will let you know when I have the results

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thank you so much.
Would you mind explaining it to me though? I understand the word boundary, but what does (?: word)? exactly do? What does the ?: stand for?

Comment: @inTOWN The `(?:` is a non-matching group; in this exact situation, it's not really necessary (you could just as simply use a `(` instead); however, I included it in case you move towards using `preg_match()`. The `?` at the end means "optional"; it may appear 0 or 1 times (it could also be written with `{0,1}` instead).

Answer (score 0):

## Fuzzy matching

Maybe an algorithm involving a `levenshtein` distance is more useful?

http://codepad.org/q4TKz5eH

```
function guess($in) {
    $in = strtolower($in);
    $known_brands = array(
        "G-STAR RAW" => array("g-star raw", "g-star"),
        "Brand-X" => array("brandx"),
        "Brand-Y" => array("brandy"),
    );
    $champion = false;
    $lowest_score = 999;
    foreach ($known_brands as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $score = levenshtein($in, $val);
            if ($score < $lowest_score) {
                $lowest_score = $score;
                $champion = $key;
            }
        }
    }
    return $champion;
}

var_dump(guess("gstar"));
var_dump(guess("G-STAR"));
var_dump(guess("Jacky"));
var_dump(guess("Brandon"));

string(10) "G-STAR RAW"
string(10) "G-STAR RAW"
string(7) "Brand-Y"
string(7) "Brand-X"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt = preg_replace('~\bg-star(?: raw)?\b~i', 'G-STAR RAW', $txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to replace string like the above you can use the following:

```
$x = preg_replace('/(G\-[starSTAR]+(\s*[rawRAW]+)?)/', 'G-STAR RAW', $x);
```

If you have strings that looks like the strings you gave us then you can use the following:

```
$x = preg_replace('/([A-Z]\-[A-Za-z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)?)/', 'G-STAR RAW', $x);
```

The last expression will match any string that starts with a capital letter, followed by a dash (-), following by any combination of lower case and upper case characters and maybe is followed by one or more characters and finaly at the end has any combination of upper case and lower case characters.